# Bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a design with a body background grey and contents are inside a white container with 20px padding.

I'm using Bootstrap to create it but if I add this 20px padding to the container then all other span elements do not fit...

It should be:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- this should be white background -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4"></div> <!-- this element should be 20px margin left --> 
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div> <!-- this element should be 20px margin right -->
    </row>
</div>
```

There is a way to create this kind of container with Bootstrap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
.container {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/) there are several predefined classes to achieve this.

Try this

```
    <div class="span4 offset1"></div> 
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4 offset4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to simply use `row-fluid`, rather than `row`, since that allows the `spanN` divs to divide up whatever's available; the `row` class gives you `span` classes that are a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

At first I would like to mention that there is a new

```
Bootstrap version (3)
```

now available.
If you still want to use your version already installed try to use the class

```
row-fluid
```

instead of row.
The

```
offset
```

classes are also possible but maybe the spacing is too large...

Comment: I know about Bootstrap 3 but it has the same problem, you cannot manage container padding... and if you do it the spans do not fit anymore... I don't need to use row-fluid...